# How to debug Rdlc expression errors - C#

Tags: rdlc

From reading several questions and answers here at SO, I know that the IIF executes both the true and false. I can't seem to understand how to correctly check and handle a null.

Here are a couple of statements I have tried that give an #Error,

```
=switch(
        First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA")="N/A", "N/A",
        First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA")<>"N/A", (FormatNumber(First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA"), 1))
    )

=IIf(
    First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA")="N/A",
    "N/A",
    IIf(
        IsNothing((First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA"))),
        "Test",
        (FormatNumber(First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA"), 1))
    )
)
```

Is there a way to get some kind of message as to what the issue is for the statement? Equally important, how can I solve the error I am receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into an issue like this a while back. It wasn't and isn't completely ideal but our work around involved passing two DataSources to the report like so:

```
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("first",  Source1 as DataTable));
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("second",  Source2 as DataTable));
```

To explain this further, Source1 and Source 2 are identical. Before the lines above, do some checking and manipulating of Source1. So the expression should look like this:

```
=switch(
        First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA1")="N/A", "N/A",
        First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA1")<>"N/A", (FormatNumber(First(Fields!ShelfLife.Value, "DQA2"), 1))
    )
```